# XSLT XPATH predicate with dynamic content inside?

Tags: xslt, dynamic, xpath, predicate

I'm trying to select only those nodes that have a value of a variable equal to a value of other variable. The exact text would be this:

`<xsl:value-of select="/data/peptides/peptide/protein_accessions[accession = ./accession/accs]" />`

But it does not work. I guess it is not possible to put a node value expression inside the predicate. But also, I find it difficult to believe. So that's why I am here asking :)

What's wrong with this expression??

Thanks!

EDIT:
The xml code would be something like this:

`<data>
<proteins>...</proteins>
<peptides><peptide>...<protein_accessions><accession>89456</accession></protein_accessions>...</peptide>...</peptides>
</data>`

And what did not work with

`<xsl:value-of select="/data/peptides/peptide/protein_accessions[accession = ./accession/accs]" />`

works with

`<xsl:value-of select="/data/peptides/peptide/protein_accessions[accession = current()/accession/accs]" />`

However, I am using this in an apply-template call, I am still not sure if this expression does what I want to do (to select all the peptide nodes with that particular number), but at least I can move on and try things :)

Thanks!

Comment: There is no variable in your XPath expression. Please get your terminology straight. (Variables look like `$variable`, you must mean something else.)

Comment: Actually, I was using the word "variable" in the meaning of variable content, so that it changed every time that the sentence was evaluated. Perhaps "dynamic" would have been a better term.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your XML this is hard to answer, but you probably mean

```
<xsl:value-of select="
  /data/peptides/peptide/protein_accessions[
    accession = current()/accession/accs
  ]
" />
```

Comment: Yes, actually the same expression with "." does not work, but with "current()" it works.

The xml code would be something like this:

<data>
<proteins>...</proteins>
<peptides><peptide>...<protein_accessions><accession>89456</accession></protein_accessions>...</peptide>...</peptides>

Comment: (sorry, not clear how the comments work, I have edited the initial question, thanks a lot!)

Answer (score 0):

> works with
>
> ```
>     <xsl:value-of select=
>       "/data/peptides/peptide/protein_accessions
>                               [accession = current()/accession/accs]" />
> ```
>
> However, I am using this in an apply-template call, I am still not
>   sure if this expression does what I want to do (to select all the
>   peptide nodes with that particular number)

**The XPath expression above clearly** *doesn't* **select any `peptide` element at all**.

All nodes it selects, if such exist, are elements named `protein_accessions`.

In case you want the appropriate `peptide` elements to be selected, use something like this:

```
/data/peptides/peptide
                [protein_accessions/accession 
                =
                 current()/accession/accs
                ]
```